# How to install ansible k8s prerequisites modules in Centos?

Tags: centos, software-installation, yum, ansible

I am using ansible shell commands to access kubernetes. I saw that ansible has few k8s modules which can be useful than shell commands.

But it has some prerequisite

openshift >= 0.6
PyYAML >= 3.11

When i tried to install PyYAML using ,it seems it could not install 3.11

> "yum install PyYAML"

,it says

```
Package PyYAML-3.10-11.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
```

and also when i tried to install openshift using yum,it shows

```
0 packages excluded due to repository protections
No package openshift available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

My linux version is as below.

```
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core) 
Release:        7.6.1810
Codename:       Core
```

How to install PyYAML and openshift which are prerequisite for k8s ansible modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the base repository of centos 7 the last version of the module PyYAML is 3.10-11
You can install the last version with "pip" utility.

First you must install pip utility (if not installed):

```
yum install python-pip
```

After this, you can install last version of PyYAML with this command:

```
pip install --upgrade PyYAML
```

You can also install openshift with pip utility:

```
pip install openshift
```